# How to fix looping error in pinescript v5?

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script, pine-script-v5

there is a bug in Pine script manual with looping - when I use the script, it does not delete all lines, that were breached. Some of them stay even though they were breached. Meaning lines continue even though they were crossed. This happes usually when there are more lines breached by candle. Any idea how to fix it?

```
//@version=5
MAX_LINES_COUNT = 100
indicator("Pivot line breaches", "", true, max_lines_count = MAX_LINES_COUNT)

color hiPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.lime, 0), "High pivots")
color loPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), "Low pivots")
int   pivotLegsInput     = input.int(5, "Pivot legs")
int   qtyOfPivotsInput   = input.int(50, "Quantity of last pivots to remember", minval = 0, maxval = MAX_LINES_COUNT / 2)
int   maxLineLengthInput = input.int(400, "Maximum line length in bars", minval = 2)

// ————— Queues a new element in an array and de-queues its first element.
qDq(array, qtyOfElements, arrayElement) =>
    array.push(array, arrayElement)
    if array.size(array) > qtyOfElements
        // Only deqeue if array has reached capacity.
        array.shift(array)

// —————— Loop through an array of lines, extending those that price has not crossed and deleting those crossed.
checkLinesForBreaches(arrayOfLines) =>
    int qtyOfLines = array.size(arrayOfLines)
    // Don't loop in case there are no lines to check because "to" value will be `na` then`.
    for lineNo = 0 to (qtyOfLines > 0 ? qtyOfLines - 1 : na)
        // Need to check that array size still warrants a loop because we may have deleted array elements in the loop.
        if lineNo < array.size(arrayOfLines)
            line  currentLine    = array.get(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
            float lineLevel      = line.get_price(currentLine, bar_index)
            bool  lineWasCrossed = math.sign(close[1] - lineLevel) != math.sign(close - lineLevel)
            bool  lineIsTooLong  = bar_index - line.get_x1(currentLine) > maxLineLengthInput
            if lineWasCrossed or lineIsTooLong
                // Line stays on the chart but will no longer be extend on further bars.
                array.remove(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
                // Force type of both local blocks to same type.
                int(na)
            else
                line.set_x2(currentLine, bar_index)
                int(na)

// Arrays of lines containing non-crossed pivot lines.
var line[] hiPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)
var line[] loPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)

// Detect new pivots.
float hiPivot = ta.pivothigh(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)
float loPivot = ta.pivotlow(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)

// Create new lines on new pivots.
if not na(hiPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], hiPivot, bar_index, hiPivot, color = hiPivotColorInput)
    line.delete(qDq(hiPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))
else if not na(loPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], loPivot, bar_index, loPivot, color = loPivotColorInput)
    line.delete(qDq(loPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))

// Extend lines if they haven't been crossed by price.
checkLinesForBreaches(hiPivotLines)
checkLinesForBreaches(loPivotLines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting the line from array and still incrementing the counter, so some lines are getting skipped. You will have to run the counter in reverse order, example below:

```
//@version=5
MAX_LINES_COUNT = 500
indicator("Pivot line breaches", "", true, max_lines_count = MAX_LINES_COUNT)

color hiPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.lime, 0), "High pivots")
color loPivotColorInput  = input(color.new(color.fuchsia, 0), "Low pivots")
int   pivotLegsInput     = input.int(5, "Pivot legs")
int   qtyOfPivotsInput   = input.int(50, "Quantity of last pivots to remember", minval = 0, maxval = MAX_LINES_COUNT / 2)
int   maxLineLengthInput = input.int(400, "Maximum line length in bars", minval = 2)

// ————— Queues a new element in an array and de-queues its first element.
qDq(array, qtyOfElements, arrayElement) =>
    array.push(array, arrayElement)
    if array.size(array) > qtyOfElements
        // Only deqeue if array has reached capacity.
        array.shift(array)

// —————— Loop through an array of lines, extending those that price has not crossed and deleting those crossed.
checkLinesForBreaches(arrayOfLines) =>
    int qtyOfLines = array.size(arrayOfLines)
    // Don't loop in case there are no lines to check because "to" value will be `na` then`.
    for lineNo1 = 0 to (qtyOfLines > 0 ? qtyOfLines - 1 : na)
        // Need to check that array size still warrants a loop because we may have deleted array elements in the loop.
        lineNo=qtyOfLines-lineNo1-1
        if lineNo < array.size(arrayOfLines)
            line  currentLine    = array.get(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
            float lineLevel      = line.get_price(currentLine, bar_index)
            bool  lineWasCrossed = math.sign(close[1] - lineLevel) != math.sign(close - lineLevel)
            bool  lineIsTooLong  = bar_index - line.get_x1(currentLine) > maxLineLengthInput
            if lineWasCrossed or lineIsTooLong
                // Line stays on the chart but will no longer be extend on further bars.
                array.remove(arrayOfLines, lineNo)
                // Force type of both local blocks to same type.
                int(na)
            else
                line.set_x2(currentLine, bar_index)
                int(na)

// Arrays of lines containing non-crossed pivot lines.
var line[] hiPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)
var line[] loPivotLines = array.new_line(qtyOfPivotsInput)

// Detect new pivots.
float hiPivot = ta.pivothigh(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)
float loPivot = ta.pivotlow(pivotLegsInput, pivotLegsInput)

// Create new lines on new pivots.
if not na(hiPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], hiPivot, bar_index, hiPivot, color = hiPivotColorInput)
    line.delete(qDq(hiPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))
else if not na(loPivot)
    line newLine = line.new(bar_index[pivotLegsInput], loPivot, bar_index, loPivot, color = loPivotColorInput)
    line.delete(qDq(loPivotLines, qtyOfPivotsInput, newLine))

// Extend lines if they haven't been crossed by price.
checkLinesForBreaches(hiPivotLines)
checkLinesForBreaches(loPivotLines)
```